# YAML: Store array as variable

Tags: ruby, yaml

I'm just starting to learn YAML, and I'm not really finding a best practice for something that I'm trying to accomplish.  Basically, I have an array of objects in my YAML file, and for production, I'd like to add 1 more entry to this array.  So I basically want something like this (it's pseudo code because I know it's not valid YAML):

```
development:
  array: &ARRAY
  - name: item1
    value: value1
  - name: item2
    value: value2

production:
  <<: *ARRAY
  array:
  - name: item3
    value: value3
```

Currently, I'm parsing my YAML files with Ruby, so I decided to handle this logic in Ruby.  I'm doing something like this:

```
yaml_contents = YAML::load(yaml_string)
prod_values = yaml_contents['production']
prod_values['array'].push({:name => 'item3', :value => 'value3'})
```

However, that can make my loading script very hairy.  Is there a better way of designing this?

I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254178/is-there-yaml-syntax-for-sharing-part-of-a-list-or-map) is related.

Comment: ok.. now i understand. Have removed my answer.

Comment: There's no way to merge sequeces in yaml, but you can replace it with a hash

Comment: But replacing with a hash means I would have to have distinct keys, which just won't be possible with how this needs to be designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<<` syntax is for merging maps (i.e. Hashes), not sequences. You could do something like this:

```
development: &ARRAY
  - name: item1
    value: value1
  - name: item2
    value: value2

production:
  - *ARRAY
  - name: item3
    value: value3
```

When you load this the `production` array will have a nested array, so you would need to use [`flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-flatten):

```
yaml_contents = YAML::load(yaml_string)
prod_values = yaml_contents['production'].flatten
```

If your actual data could involve nested hashes and you only want to flatten any arrays that appear as aliases in the Yaml you could write your own Psych visitor (probably a sub class of [`Psych::Visitors::ToRuby`](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/master/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb)) and merge them in as you create the object graph, but I suspect simply calling `flatten` will be enough in this case.

Comment: I think you're absolutely right... I believe this is the answer.  I'm going to do some more extensive testing first.  Thanks!