# Yaml asterisk syntax with docker compose volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

### My goal is to recuse duplicated volume definition within each service

I read the following Stackoverflow questions/answers but they did not help:

- [YAML: Store array as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425486/yaml-store-array-as-variable)
- [What do the &,<<, * mean in this database.yml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651275/what-do-the-mean-in-this-database-yml-file)

##### Current attempts:

**Variant 1:**
Using `default-volumes` with a dash prefix like every array entry has to (relates to the first SO question)

```yaml
version: '2.4'

x-default-volumes: &default-volumes
  - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
  
x-default-service: &default-service
  image: my-image-name:my-tag
  restart: unless-stopped
  volumes:
    *default-volumes
  networks:
    my-network:
    
services:
  service1:
    <<: *default-service
    image: service1-image:tag
  
  service2:
    <<: *default-service
    image: service2-image:tag
    volumes:
      - *default-volumes
      - service2:/path/on/container

    
networks:
  my-network:
  
volumes:
  service2: {}
```

`docker-compose config`

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
> services.service2.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be a string, or an object

**Variant 2:**
An alternative attempt...

```yaml
version: '2.4'

x-default-volumes: &default-volumes
  - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
  
x-default-service: &default-service
  image: my-image-name:my-tag
  restart: unless-stopped
  volumes:
    *default-volumes
  networks:
    my-network:
    
services:
  service1:
    <<: *default-service
    image: service1-image:tag
  
  service2:
    <<: *default-service
    image: service2-image:tag
    volumes:
      *default-volumes
      - service2:/path/on/container

    
networks:
  my-network:
  
volumes:
  service2: {}
```

`docker-compose config`

> ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
> in "./docker-compose.yml", line 20, column 5
> expected , but found ''
> in "./docker-compose.yml", line 24, column 7

Without the usage of the asterisk character in the `service2` volumes definition, a `docker-compose config` command yields a valid result.

```yaml
version: '2.4'

x-default-volumes: &default-volumes
  - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
  
x-default-service: &default-service
  image: my-image-name:my-tag
  restart: unless-stopped
  volumes:
    *default-volumes
  networks:
    my-network:
    
services:
  service1:
    <<: *default-service
    image: service1-image:tag
  
  service2:
    <<: *default-service
    image: service2-image:tag
    volumes:
      *default-volumes
      - service2:/path/on/container

    
networks:
  my-network:
  
volumes:
  service2: {}
```

**Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this goal? Thanks in advance.**

### Edit 1:

As David Maze pointed out: There is no valid yaml solution to this problem. He also found a similar question ([Is there a way to alias/anchor an array in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948933/is-there-a-way-to-alias-anchor-an-array-in-yaml)) in which some kind of reuse is described.

I ended up using the following result:

```yaml
version: '2.4'

x-volumes:
  - &volume-localtime
    /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro

x-default-service: &default-service
  image: my-image-name:my-tag
  restart: unless-stopped
  volumes:
    - *volume-localtime
  networks:
    my-network:

services:
  service1:
    <<: *default-service
    image: service1-image:tag

  service2:
    <<: *default-service
    image: service2-image:tag
    volumes:
      - *volume-localtime
      - service2:/path/on/container


networks:
  my-network:

volumes:
  service2: {}
```

Comment: [Is there a way to alias/anchor an array in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948933/is-there-a-way-to-alias-anchor-an-array-in-yaml) claims "There's no way of merging sequences on YAML level", which is what would be required here.  Can you have fewer volumes such that repeating them isn't an imposition?

Comment: Fewer volumes are no choice. I will try the linked answer and check if this may work. Still more lines but at least one way.

Comment: With this attempt some kind of duplication removal is achived. Since there is no other way ill stick to it. Thank you!