# Include One Yaml File Inside Another

Tags: python, yaml, config, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I want to have a base config file which is used by other config files to share common config.

E.g if I have one file `base.yml` with

```
foo: 1

bar:
  - 2
  - 3
```

And then a second file `some_file.yml` with

```
foo: 2

baz: "baz"
```

What I'd want to end up with a merged config file with

```
foo: 2

bar:
  - 2
  - 3

baz: "baz"
```

It's easy enough to write a custom loader that handles an `!include` tag.

```
class ConfigLoader(yaml.SafeLoader):

    def __init__(self, stream):
        super().__init__(stream)
        self._base = Path(stream.name).parent

    def include(self, node):
        file_name = self.construct_scalar(node)
        file_path = self._base.joinpath(file_name)

        with file_path.open("rt") as fh:
            return yaml.load(fh, IncludeLoader)
```

Then I can parse an `!include` tag. So if my file is

```
inherit:
   !include base.yml

foo: 2

baz: "baz"
```

But now the base config is a mapping. I.e. if I load the the file I'll end up with

```py
config = {'a': [42], 'c': [3.6, [1, 2, 3]], 'include': [{'a': 1, 'b': [1.43, 543.55]}]}
```

But if I don't make the tag part of a mapping, e.g.

```
!include base.yml

foo: 2

baz: "baz"
```

I get an error. `yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here`.

But I know that the yaml parser can parse tags without needing a mapping. Because I can do things like

```
!!python/object:foo.Bar
x: 1.0   
y: 3.14
```

So how do I write a loader and/or structure my YAML file so that I can include another file in my configuration?

Comment: The [recommended file extension](http://yaml.org/faq.html) for *YAML* files has been  `.yaml` since 2006, when are you going to catch up? 
The [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) format is XML based, and at least as old as YAML.

Comment: why do you invent a yaml grammer, i thought there could be a third yaml file defining which files should be mreged and to what file.

Comment: Can you update your question with the full minimal working program generating the `config = ` line? Or at least Include the definition of `IncludeLoader`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In YAML you cannot mix scalars, mapping keys and sequence elements. This is invalid YAML:

```
- abc
d: e
```

and so is this

```
some_file_name
a: b
```

and that you have that scalar quoted, and provide a tag does of course not change the fact
that it is invalid YAML.

As you can already found out, you can trick the loader into returning a `dict` instead of
the string (just like the parser already has built in constructors for non-primitive types like `datetime.date`).

That this:

```
!!python/object:foo.Bar
x: 1.0
y: 3.14
```

works is because the whole mapping is tagged, where you just tag a scalar value.

What also would be invalid syntax:

```
!include base.yaml
foo: 2
baz: baz
```

but you could do:

```
!include
filename: base.yaml
foo: 2
baz: baz
```

and process the 'filename' key in a special way, or make
the `!include` tag an empty key:

```
!include : base.yaml  # : is a valid tag character, so you need the space
foo: 2
baz: baz
```

I would however look at using merge keys, as merging is essentially what
you are trying to do. The following YAML works:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from pathlib import Path

yaml_str = """
<<: {x: 42, y: 196, foo: 3}
foo: 2
baz: baz
"""
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
yaml.default_flow_style = False
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
baz: baz
foo: 2
x: 42
y: 196
```

So you should be able to do:

```
<<: !load base.yaml
foo: 2
baz: baz
```

and anyone with knowledge of merge keys would know what happens if `base.yaml` does include the key `foo` with value `3`,
and would also understand:

```
<<: [!load base.yaml, !load config.yaml]
foo: 2
baz: baz
```

(As I tend to associate "including" with textual including as in the C preprocessor, I think `!load' might be a
more appropriate tag, but that is probably a matter of taste).

To get the merge keys to work, it is probably easiest to just sublass the `Constructor`, as merging is done before tag resolving:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.nodes import MappingNode, SequenceNode, ScalarNode
from ruamel.yaml.constructor import ConstructorError
from ruamel.yaml.compat import _F
from pathlib import Path



class MyConstructor(ruamel.yaml.constructor.SafeConstructor):
    def flatten_mapping(self, node):
        # type: (Any) -> Any
        """
        This implements the merge key feature http://yaml.org/type/merge.html
        by inserting keys from the merge dict/list of dicts if not yet
        available in this node
        """
        merge = []  # type: List[Any]
        index = 0
        while index < len(node.value):
            key_node, value_node = node.value[index]
            if key_node.tag == 'tag:yaml.org,2002:merge':
                if merge:  # double << key
                    if self.allow_duplicate_keys:
                        del node.value[index]
                        index += 1
                        continue
                    args = [
                        'while constructing a mapping',
                        node.start_mark,
                        'found duplicate key "{}"'.format(key_node.value),
                        key_node.start_mark,
                        """
                        To suppress this check see:
                           http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#duplicate-keys
                        """,
                        """\
                        Duplicate keys will become an error in future releases, and are errors
                        by default when using the new API.
                        """,
                    ]
                    if self.allow_duplicate_keys is None:
                        warnings.warn(DuplicateKeyFutureWarning(*args))
                    else:
                        raise DuplicateKeyError(*args)
                del node.value[index]
                if isinstance(value_node, ScalarNode) and value_node.tag == '!load':
                    file_path = None
                    try:
                        if self.loader.reader.stream is not None:
                            file_path = Path(self.loader.reader.stream.name).parent / value_node.value
                    except AttributeError:
                        pass
                    if file_path is None:
                        file_path = Path(value_node.value)
                    # there is a bug in ruamel.yaml<=0.17.20 that prevents
                    # the use of a Path as argument to compose()
                    with file_path.open('rb') as fp:
                        merge.extend(ruamel.yaml.YAML().compose(fp).value)
                elif isinstance(value_node, MappingNode):
                    self.flatten_mapping(value_node)
                    print('vn0', type(value_node.value), value_node.value)
                    merge.extend(value_node.value)
                elif isinstance(value_node, SequenceNode):
                    submerge = []
                    for subnode in value_node.value:
                        if not isinstance(subnode, MappingNode):
                            raise ConstructorError(
                                'while constructing a mapping',
                                node.start_mark,
                                _F(
                                    'expected a mapping for merging, but found {subnode_id!s}',
                                    subnode_id=subnode.id,
                                ),
                                subnode.start_mark,
                            )
                        self.flatten_mapping(subnode)
                        submerge.append(subnode.value)
                    submerge.reverse()
                    for value in submerge:
                        merge.extend(value)
                else:
                    raise ConstructorError(
                        'while constructing a mapping',
                        node.start_mark,
                        _F(
                            'expected a mapping or list of mappings for merging, '
                            'but found {value_node_id!s}',
                            value_node_id=value_node.id,
                        ),
                        value_node.start_mark,
                    )
            elif key_node.tag == 'tag:yaml.org,2002:value':
                key_node.tag = 'tag:yaml.org,2002:str'
                index += 1
            else:
                index += 1
        if bool(merge):
            node.merge = merge  # separate merge keys to be able to update without duplicate
            node.value = merge + node.value


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe', pure=True)
yaml.default_flow_style = False
yaml.Constructor = MyConstructor



yaml_str = """\
<<: !load base.yaml
foo: 2
baz: baz
"""

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
print('---')

file_name = Path('test.yaml')
file_name.write_text("""\
<<: !load base.yaml
bar: 2
baz: baz
""")

data = yaml.load(file_name)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

this prints:

```
bar:
- 2
- 3
baz: baz
foo: 2
---
bar: 2
baz: baz
foo: 1
```

Notes:

- don't open YAML files as text. They are written binary (UTF-8), and you should load them as such (`open(filename, 'rb')`).
- If you had included a full working program in your question (or at least included the text of `IncludeLoader`, it
  would have
  been possible to provide a full working example with the merge keys (or find out for you that it
  doesn't work for some reason)
- as it is, it is unclear if your `yaml.load()` is an instance method call (`import ruamel.yaml; yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()`) or calling a function (`from ruamel import yaml`). You should not use the latter as it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend these 2 steps:

1. write or plug-in a *custom load-constructor* for **including** other files
2. *structure the YAML* for **merging** other keys (within the same file)
   or **including** other files

Similar to what [Anthon, author and maintainer of `ruamel.yaml` answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71076484/5730279) ... but with `pyyaml`.

#### How to merge in YAML keys (from within same file)

See the YAML [*merge*](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) syntax `<<:` is for **merging in keys**:

```
---
- &OTHER { foo: 1, bar: [2, 3] }

# merge it in from above
<< : OTHER 

# the base
foo: 1

bar:
  - 2
  - 3
```

#### How to include YAML files

YAML markup syntax has no include-directive or similar.
But each YAML-parser implementation can offer this feature.

For example, see another [answer of Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9577670/5730279) which has does so:

> **PyYAML** allows you to attach **custom constructors** (such as `!include`) to the YAML loader.

This constructor can be plugged-in by [`pyyaml-include`](https://pypi.org/project/pyyaml-include/) does:

```
import yaml
from yamlinclude import YamlIncludeConstructor

YamlIncludeConstructor.add_to_loader_class(loader_class=yaml.FullLoader, base_dir='/your/conf/dir')  # or specify another dir relatively or absolutely
# default is: include YAML files from current working directory

with open('base.yaml') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

print(data)
```

To **include** (not merging in) a second file `some_file.yaml` (located in same directory) given as:

```
foo: 1

bar:
  - 2
  - 3
```

within the `base.yaml` add:

```
!include some_file.yaml    # includes the file on top-level (relative path!)

foo: 1

bar:
  - 2
  - 3
```

See also:

- [Are there specifiers to merge keys in yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39012631/are-there-specifiers-to-merge-keys-in-yaml)
- [How can I include a YAML file inside another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528281/how-can-i-include-a-yaml-file-inside-another)
- [merge two yaml files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47424865/merge-two-yaml-files-in-python)

#### Recommended filename extension

From Wikipedia, [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML):

> The **official recommended** filename extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` since 2006.[12](https://yaml.org/faq.html)

(sourced from the official YAML-FAQ: "YAML Ain't Markup Language". September 24, 2006. Archived from the original on 2006-09-24.)

Comment: It is good to know that someone read my [contribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=YAML&diff=881879577&oldid=879937809) to Wikipedia.