# Is it possible to store artifact into Circle CI during the multi-stage build?

Tags: pipeline, circleci, artifact

I have `test` and `deploy` paths into the workflow and when I sequentially execute them `deploy` overrides `artifact`.

Is it possible to keep it, so it will be passed from stage to stage sequentially? Store `artifact` into `Slack` or any other system is not an option due to limitations in the development environment.

Comment: Providing formatted example config here will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Circle CI` provides the solution through [`workspace`](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#using-workspaces-to-share-data-among-jobs).

To share `artifact` or any set of files, you need to `persist_to_workspace` into the `test` stage and `attach_to_workspace` on the `deploy` stage.

The only catch is to persist `artifact` on the `deploy` phase. `workspace` itself is available for not more than 30 days.