# Job config: add an element to an existing list of files

Tags: zuul-ci

I'm trying to work with list variables in ZUUL jobs to avoid duplicating definitions of file exclusion patterns.
Now I have a job definition that looks like this:

```
- job:
name: base-job
vars:
  my_set_of_files: &myFileSet
    - ^.README.*
    - ^.*.md

- job:
    name: foo
    parent: base-job
    irrelevant_files: *myFileSet

- job:
    name: bar
    parent: base-job
    irrelevant_files: *myFileSet
      - *.xml
```

But while 'foo' works nicely, I don't seem to be able to add another element for my 'bar' job.

How can I reuse, but slightly modify the list 'myFileSet' in another job config?

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigation I discovered that referencing a list is a yaml feature, not a ZUUL feature.

The same problem has already been discussed e.g. here:
[Is there YAML syntax for sharing part of a list or map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254178/is-there-yaml-syntax-for-sharing-part-of-a-list-or-map) and here: [How to merge YAML arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090177/how-to-merge-yaml-arrays/30770740)

Unfortunately, there is no native solution. The links above are also discussing notation solutions that are based on using a custom parser, which is not an option within ZUUL. So it does not seem to be possible as such.

Instead, I will either defien multiple variants of this list, or define the irrelevant files explicitly.