# Is it possible to DRY up yaml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, yaml, dry, cross-reference

I am using Rails' 4.1.4 YAML locale files to store some translations, for example:

```
en:
  words:
    en:
      passport: "passport"
      ticket: "ticket"
      train: "train"
de:
  words:
    en:
      passport: "passport"
      ticket: "ticket"
      train: "train"
```

With this I can use `t("words.#{to_language}.train")` to return `train` for a German user (I18n.locale == :de) who has chosen english as his `to_language`.

My question is: is there any way I can not repeat myself and have something like code below?

```
en OR de:
  words:
    en:
      passport: "passport"
      ticket: "ticket"
      train: "train"
```

Perhaps I can assign all the content of words to a variable and then just do:

```
en:
  all_words
de:
  all_words
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
all_words: &all_words
  words:
    en:
      passport: "passport"
      ticket: "ticket"
      train: "train"

en:
  <<: *all_words

de:
  <<: *all_words
```

And you course you can then specify the key and it will override the included default.

Checkout this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6651436/7223300) that discusses what &, *, << mean.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, YAML allows you to [repeat nodes via reference](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760395). In particular, Ruby's YAML has something nonstandard called a ["merge key"](http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#merge_key), which will be useful in your particular situation.

For example, if you have, say:

```
base_fruits: &default # Alias the keys here into `default`.
  apple: one
  banana: two
```

then you can do

```
fruit_basket_one:
  <<: *default        # Include all the keys from the alias `default`.
  coconut: three      # Add another key too.

fruit_basket_two:
  <<: *default
  durian: five
  pear: six
```

So you can do something like:

```
en:
  words:
    en: &all_en_words
      passport: "passport"
      ticket: "ticket"
      train: "train"

de:
  words:
    en:
      <<: *all_en_words
      custom_word: "custom translation"
```

I would say that this probably isn't the right way to go about it, though. If a `de` user wants `en` translations, then they should just use `en`. Otherwise you will need an N^2 mapping for every pair of (actual language, desired language), instead of just a list of N translations, which is far easier to maintain.