# changing database.yml for postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've just made my first ruby on rails app and want to change my database to postgresql in order to use it with heroku. So far I've done this, but I think it's not working correctly. Can you please tell me if you see anything wrong? Thanks

database.yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: myrubyblog
  user: myrubyblog
  password: 
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: myrubyblog
  user: myrubyblog
  password: 

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: myrubyblog
  user: myrubyblog
  password: 

production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: myrubyblog
  user: myrubyblog
  password:
```

I've also changed gem 'sqlite3' into gem 'pg' in Gemfile

Comment: It might help if you were able to expand on "but I think it's not working correctly"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work (assuming the user & password are correct in postgres)

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  user: myrubyblog
  password: 
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myrubyblog

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myrubyblog
```

See [What do the &,<<, * mean in this database.yml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651275/what-do-the-mean-in-this-database-yml-file) for how `&default` is re-used for each of the database definitions.

You don't need to define a production env in your `database.yml`; heroku will create its own version of `database.yml` for use in production.

See http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database for more details about the configuration in database.yml

Running `rails new myblogapp --database=postgresql` will create a new `myblogapp` application with the appropriate content in `database.yml` customized for using with postgres.

Answer (score -1):

It appears to depend on your Rails version. Heroku gives instructions here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-ruby